# Failed to create SQLite DB in my Samsung y duos device in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have android application . its working most of the devices , but it didn't work in the `Samsung y duos` only.

my application database contain 6 tables, 2 tables data is encrypted. Without this encryption , it was working fine, after put encrypted data only i am getting this issue.

Its error is :

```
    01-20 07:03:27.791: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(13747): sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database corruption at line 48188 of [ed759d5a9e], db=/data/data/com_group_mylibs/databases/mylibs_db
01-20 07:03:27.791: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(13747): sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database disk image is malformed, db=/data/data/com_group_mylibs/databases/mylibs_db
01-20 07:03:27.791: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(13747): sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database corruption at line 48188 of [ed759d5a9e], db=/data/data/com_group_mylibs/databases/mylibs_db
01-20 07:03:27.791: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(13747): sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database disk image is malformed, db=/data/data/com_group_mylibs/databases/mylibs_db
01-20 07:03:27.791: E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(13747): sqlite3_exec - Failed to set synchronous mode = 1(Normal) 
01-20 07:03:27.791: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(13747): sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database corruption at line 48188 of [ed759d5a9e], db=/data/data/com_group_mylibs/databases/mylibs_db
01-20 07:03:27.791: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(13747): sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database disk image is malformed, db=/data/data/com_group_mylibs/databases/mylibs_db
01-20 07:03:27.791: E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(13747): CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed
01-20 07:03:27.791: E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(13747): Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /data/data/com.group.mylibs/databases/mylibs.db
01-20 07:03:27.801: E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(13747): deleting the database file: /data/data/com.group.mylibs/databases/mylibs.db
01-20 07:03:28.001: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(13747): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: hint, db=/data/data/com_group.mylibs/databases/mylibs_db
01-20 07:03:28.001: W/dalvikvm(13747): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c31a68)
01-20 07:03:28.011: E/AndroidRuntime(13747): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 07:03:28.011: E/AndroidRuntime(13747): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.group.mylibs/com.group.mylibs.LibraryActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: hint: , while compiling: SELECT id, wordTypeId, hintText FROM hint WHERE wordTypeId= 0
```

This is my code :

```
public class MyLibsDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mylibs.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.group.mylibs/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "mylibs.db";
private final Context myContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mylibsDataBase;

public SQLiteDatabase getMylibsDataBase() {
    return mylibsDataBase;
}

public void setMylibsDataBase(SQLiteDatabase mylibsDataBase) {
    this.mylibsDataBase = mylibsDataBase;
}



public MyLibsDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    myContext = context;
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    try {
        createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
}



@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time open the application.
 * 
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try
    {
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME); 
    return dbFile.exists();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("Error checkDataBase", ex.toString());
    return false;
}
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    try {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Error copyDataBase", ex.toString());
    }
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    this.mylibsDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
```

This application is working fine with most of the emulator & device , problem only in  `Samsung y duos` .

I checked sqlite version 3.7  & i created database version is 3.6.18.

please tell me what is an issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this.getReadableDatabase(); is your problem replace it with getwritabledatabase

Comment: No. I have tried that also. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the Android Source code it seems that class [DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler.java)
indicates that your database is corrupted. Looking into `DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler.java` and your logs suggests that `onCorruption()` of `DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler.java` class is being called and that method further deletes your database. So, the 2 tables that you have added for encryption may be causing the problem. I suggest you to please check those 2 table if they are creating any corruption to your whole database.