# database error on Samsung devices

Tags: android, sqlite, samsung-mobile

I'm having some trouble with Samsung devices. In my app, everytime i upload a new version on market, i want to replace the database...but before i tried to save some data. The code works fine on ADV and in a lot of devices, except in devices like Samsung Galaxy (S series, tab).

I already tried do chance this.getReadableDatabase() to this.getWritableDatabase() but nothing changes.

I also checked this similar post [Failed to create SQLite DB in my Samsung y duos device in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228158/failed-to-create-sqlite-db-in-my-samsung-y-duos-device-in-android)

Someone can help me? Below is the basic code and my try

```
...
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{     
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    if(dbExist){

    }else{
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        db.close();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created"); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Erro ao copiar banco");
        }
    }
}
/*
Both file or a database check works 
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    File checkDB = new File (Bd_path + Bd_name);
    return checkDB.exists();

    /*SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = Bd_path + Bd_name;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;*/
}
...
```

First try - Works fine except on Samsung devices

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{     
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    if(dbExist){
        try {
            openDataBase();
            Cursor resul = bancoDados.rawQuery("Select ativo from configuracao", null);
            resul.moveToFirst();
            if (Integer.valueOf(resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("ativo"))) <= 1) {
                copyDataBase();
                Log.v("Data", "updated");
                bancoDados.execSQL("UPDATE configuracao SET ativo = '2'");
            }
            resul.close();
            bancoDados.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
...
```

Second try - Works fine except on Samsung devices

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{     
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    if(dbExist){
        try {
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor resul = db.rawQuery("Select ativo from configuracao", null);
            resul.moveToFirst();
            if (Integer.valueOf(resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("ativo"))) <= 1) {
                copyDataBase();
                Log.v("Data", "updated");
                db.execSQL("UPDATE configuracao SET ativo = '2'");
            }
            resul.close();
            db.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
...
```

i got the flowing error when the devices try to read my database

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: configuracao: , while compiling: Select ativo from configuracao
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:110)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:71)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1324)
at com.ead.louvemosfinal.Dados_banco.createDataBase(Dados_banco.java:47)
at com.ead.louvemosfinal.DataAdapter.createDatabase(DataAdapter.java:31)
at com.ead.louvemosfinal.Inicio.construtor(Inicio.java:116)
at com.ead.louvemosfinal.Inicio.onCreateView(Inicio.java:97)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:279)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:6177)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1266)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1271)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1271)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1271)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:771)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1868)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3709)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When it read the database, fail on load the data from this table on the following class (Inicio.class)

```
Code of Inicio.class
...
bancoDados = new DataAdapter(getActivity());
bancoDados.createDatabase();
bancoDados.open();
settings = bancoDados.carregaConfiguracao()
bancoDados.close();
...
```

The error i got

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: configuracao: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM configuracao
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1357)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1325)
at com.ead.louvemosfinal.DataAdapter.carregaConfiguracao(DataAdapter.java:429)
at com.ead.louvemosfinal.Inicio.construtor(Inicio.java:118)
at com.ead.louvemosfinal.Inicio.onCreateView(Inicio.java:97)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:279)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:6156)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1122)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1127)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1127)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1127)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:773)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1867)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The carregaConfiguracao code from DataAdapter

```
public String[] carregaConfiguracao(){
    Cursor resul = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM configuracao", null);
    String[] dados = new String[11];
    resul.moveToFirst();
        dados[0] = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        dados[1] = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("fonte"));
        dados[2] = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("nome"));
        dados[3] = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("email"));
        dados[4] = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("cor_nota"));
        dados[5] = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("cor_letra"));
        dados[6] = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("contraste"));
        dados[7] = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("refrao"));
        dados[8] = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("acordes"));
        dados[9] = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("musica"));
        dados[10] = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("cantor"));
        resul.close();
    return dados;

}
```

Comment: are you sure there is a table called configuracao ?

Comment: Yes...only samsung devices don't see this table

Comment: could you please tell the path that you are copying the database to ?

Comment: "/data/data/com.ead.louvemosfinal/databases/"

Comment: what is the extension of your SQLite database ?

Comment: Hi Guys already solved this error. After i created my db, i put some data in the table configuracao...and further ahead i add another field to this table. With luck...one of samsung devices gave me a different error that i describe above (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed). Then i deleted the table configuracao and recreate it...problem solved..ty for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

use this DataBaseHandler Calss.it is work me for all the android deveices.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler {

    // Database
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Heat";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // field
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";

    private static final String KEY_TAGS_COLOR = "tag_color";
    private static final String KEY_TAGS_TAG_ID = "tag_id";
    private static final String KEY_TAGS_DESCRIPTION = "tag_description";
    private static final String KEY_TAGS_FLAG_ACTIVE = "isActive";

    // TABLES
    private static final String TABLE_NAME_USER_DETAIL = "user_details";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME_TAGS = "tags";

    // CREATE TABLES

    private static final String CREATE_TAGS_TABLE = "create table "
            + TABLE_NAME_TAGS + " ( " + KEY_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement," + KEY_TAGS_TAG_ID
            + " integer," + KEY_TAGS_DESCRIPTION + " text ," + KEY_TAGS_COLOR
            + " text ," + KEY_TAGS_FLAG_ACTIVE + " text ); ";

    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHandler";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(CREATE_TAGS_TABLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public DatabaseHandler open() throws SQLException {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public void insertTagList(List<YourModelCalss> tag_list) {
        if (tag_list == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (YourModelCalss tags : tag_list) {
            insertTag(tags);
        }
    }

    private void insertTag(YourModelCalss tags) {
        // AppLog.Log(TAG, "Inserting into Database TAG :: " + tags.getDesc());

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_TAGS_TAG_ID, tags.getId());
        values.put(KEY_TAGS_DESCRIPTION, tags.getDesc());
        values.put(KEY_TAGS_COLOR, tags.getColor());
        int active_flag = 0;

        if (tags.getFlag_active() != null
                && tags.getFlag_active().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            active_flag = 1;
        }
        values.put(KEY_TAGS_FLAG_ACTIVE, active_flag);
        try {
            open();
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME_TAGS, null, values);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        close();
    }

    public ArrayList<YourModelCalss> getTagList() {
        ArrayList<YourModelCalss> tagList = new ArrayList<YourModelCalss>();

        open();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME_TAGS, new String[] {
                KEY_TAGS_TAG_ID, KEY_TAGS_DESCRIPTION, KEY_TAGS_COLOR,
                KEY_TAGS_FLAG_ACTIVE }, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            YourModelCalss tag;
            do {
                tag = new YourModelCalss();
                tag.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                tag.setDesc(cursor.getString(1));
                tag.setColor(cursor.getString(2));
                tag.setFlag_active(cursor.getString(3));

                tagList.add(tag);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }

        cursor.close();
        cursor = null;
        close();

        return tagList;
    }

    public void clearTagData() {
        try {
            open();
            db.delete(TABLE_NAME_TAGS, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close();
        }

    }

}
```